# How can I use the output from a previous iteration as the input for a new iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

I just want to run a simple code that uses the output of the previous iteration as the input for the newest iteration. I sort of want it along the lines of this.

```
a_1 = 2
a_2 = 3 * (a_(n-1))
a_2 = 6
```

The code I've included below is just what I would like, and doesn't reflect what I think the actual code should look like.

```
import numpy as np

Nloop = 10
cList = np.zeros(Nloop)

a_1  = 2  #Setting my inital value
cList[0] = a_1

for y in range(Nloop):
    a = cList[y-1]  # I know this isn't right, but for this I just
                    # want to get the output from the last iteration
    a_n = a * 3
    cList[y] = a_n
```

I want the result to look something like this:

```
print(cList)
[2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458, 4374, 13122, 36366]
```

Any instructions/help/hints would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Simply start `y` from `1` instead of `0` by making the following change:

```
for y in range(1, Nloop):
```

As a side note, your whole program can be rewritten as:

```
>>> print([2 * (3 ** i) for i in range(10)])
[2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458, 4374, 13122, 39366]
```